# How can I combine my LESS file with the default bootstrap less file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I am trying to create a different panel from the twitter bootstrap LESS and hence I created a new LESS file and named it **panel.less**. However, twitter bootstrap already have their default LESS file for panels which is called **panels.less**.

How can I combine them so that it would process my less file too?(This might not be the correct word)

Panel.less

`

```
.panel-profile .panel-heading {
    position: relative;
}
.panel-profile .panel-heading  h4 {
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.panel-profile .panel-heading img {
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;
}
@media (min-width:400px) {
    .panel-profile .panel-heading a {
        font-size: .75em;
        float: right;
    }
   .panael-profile .panel-heading {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
  .panel-profile .panel-heading img {
        position: absolute;
        margin: 0;
        display: inline;
        bottom: -25px;
    }
}
```

`

Bootstrap.less. - This is my version not the default
`

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

// Reset
@import "normalize.less";
@import "print.less";

// Core CSS
@import "scaffolding.less";
@import "type.less";
@import "grid.less";
@import "forms.less";
@import "buttons.less";

// Components
@import "component-animations.less";
@import "muicons.less";
@import "dropdowns.less";
@import "button-groups.less";
@import "navs.less";
@import "navbar.less";
@import "media.less";
@import "list-group.less";
@import "close.less";
@import "panel.less";
```

`

Panels.less
`
    //
    // Panels
    // --------------------------------------------------

```
// Base class
.panel {
  margin-bottom: @line-height-computed;
  background-color: @panel-bg;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: @panel-border-radius;
  .box-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05));
}

// Panel contents
.panel-body {
  padding: @panel-body-padding;
  &:extend(.clearfix all);
}

// Optional heading
.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  .border-top-radius((@panel-border-radius - 1));

  > .dropdown .dropdown-toggle {
    color: inherit;
  }
}

// Within heading, strip any `h*` tag of its default margins for spacing.
.panel-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: ceil((@font-size-base * 1.125));
  color: inherit;

  > a {
    color: inherit;
  }
}

// Optional footer (stays gray in every modifier class)
.panel-footer {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: @panel-footer-bg;
  border-top: 1px solid @panel-inner-border;
  .border-bottom-radius((@panel-border-radius - 1));
}


// List groups in panels
//
// By default, space out list group content from panel headings to account for
// any kind of custom content between the two.

.panel {
  > .list-group {
    margin-bottom: 0;

    .list-group-item {
      border-width: 1px 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    // Add border top radius for first one
    &:first-child {
      .list-group-item:first-child {
        border-top: 0;
        .border-top-radius((@panel-border-radius - 1));
      }
    }
    // Add border bottom radius for last one
    &:last-child {
      .list-group-item:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0;
        .border-bottom-radius((@panel-border-radius - 1));
      }
    }
  }
}
// Collapse space between when there's no additional content.
.panel-heading + .list-group {
  .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-width: 0;
  }
}


// Tables in panels
//
// Place a non-bordered `.table` within a panel (not within a `.panel-body`) and
// watch it go full width.

.panel {
  > .table,
  > .table-responsive > .table {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  // Add border top radius for first one
  > .table:first-child,
  > .table-responsive:first-child > .table:first-child {
    .border-top-radius((@panel-border-radius - 1));

    > thead:first-child,
    > tbody:first-child {
      > tr:first-child {
        td:first-child,
        th:first-child {
          border-top-left-radius: (@panel-border-radius - 1);
        }
        td:last-child,
        th:last-child {
          border-top-right-radius: (@panel-border-radius - 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Add border bottom radius for last one
  > .table:last-child,
  > .table-responsive:last-child > .table:last-child {
    .border-bottom-radius((@panel-border-radius - 1));

    > tbody:last-child,
    > tfoot:last-child {
      > tr:last-child {
        td:first-child,
        th:first-child {
          border-bottom-left-radius: (@panel-border-radius - 1);
        }
        td:last-child,
        th:last-child {
          border-bottom-right-radius: (@panel-border-radius - 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  > .panel-body + .table,
  > .panel-body + .table-responsive {
    border-top: 1px solid @table-border-color;
  }
  > .table > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child th,
  > .table > tbody:first-child > tr:first-child td {
    border-top: 0;
  }
  > .table-bordered,
  > .table-responsive > .table-bordered {
    border: 0;
    > thead,
    > tbody,
    > tfoot {
      > tr {
        > th:first-child,
        > td:first-child {
          border-left: 0;
        }
        > th:last-child,
        > td:last-child {
          border-right: 0;
        }
      }
    }
    > thead,
    > tbody {
      > tr:first-child {
        > td,
        > th {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }
    > tbody,
    > tfoot {
      > tr:last-child {
        > td,
        > th {
          border-bottom: 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  > .table-responsive {
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}


// Collapsable panels (aka, accordion)
//
// Wrap a series of panels in `.panel-group` to turn them into an accordion with
// the help of our collapse JavaScript plugin.

.panel-group {
  margin-bottom: @line-height-computed;

  // Tighten up margin so it's only between panels
  .panel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: @panel-border-radius;
    overflow: hidden; // crop contents when collapsed
    + .panel {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
  }

  .panel-heading {
    border-bottom: 0;
    + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
      border-top: 1px solid @panel-inner-border;
    }
  }
  .panel-footer {
    border-top: 0;
    + .panel-collapse .panel-body {
      border-bottom: 1px solid @panel-inner-border;
    }
  }
}


// Contextual variations
.panel-default {
  .panel-variant(@panel-default-border; @panel-default-text; @panel-default-heading-bg; @panel-default-border);
}
.panel-primary {
  .panel-variant(@panel-primary-border; @panel-primary-text; @panel-primary-heading-bg; @panel-primary-border);
}
.panel-success {
  .panel-variant(@panel-success-border; @panel-success-text; @panel-success-heading-bg; @panel-success-border);
}
.panel-info {
  .panel-variant(@panel-info-border; @panel-info-text; @panel-info-heading-bg; @panel-info-border);
}
.panel-warning {
  .panel-variant(@panel-warning-border; @panel-warning-text; @panel-warning-heading-bg; @panel-warning-border);
}
.panel-danger {
  .panel-variant(@panel-danger-border; @panel-danger-text; @panel-danger-heading-bg; @panel-danger-border);
}
```

`

WORKS: I not sure what went wrong but I went to combine my panel LESS file with the default panel LESS file together and managed to get the results. But I am sure that is the wrong way to compile it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create an app-specific version of the main bootstrap file, let's call it `app-bootstrap.less`. Just copy the contents of the default `bootstrap.less` into this file. Here's also your chance to comment out parts of bootstrap that you're not using (e.g. popovers, panels, forms etc). Alternatively you could just do `@import "bootstrap.less";` if you're using all of it.

What you'd do next is to add in your own `panels.less`. The directory search order used is likely determined by your setup, but I guess it would not be an easy task having `@import "panels.less";` in `app-bootstrap.less` mean one thing (i.e. "import `panels.less` from local directory") and another in `panels.less` (i.e. "import `panels.less` from bootstrap). Therefore, what you could do is put your panel additions in `app-panels.less`instead and make sure that file is imported in your `app-bootstrap.less`.

Comment: I would get an error just by entering @import "panels.less"; into the app-bootstrap.less. 

The error was that the file can't be found. But i tried writing the whole directory out too and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: How do you compile your less source? Browser or command line? I nearly always run less as part of a grunt task, which let's be specify a number of include paths that will be searched for less files. If you are using `lessc` the option is [`--include-path=PATH1;PATH2`](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-include-paths).

Answer (score 0):

You can include the bootstrap.less file (`@import "path";`) in your less file and then compile it - that way you'll overwrite the class in the "CSS way". Or you can include all the files that are included in bootstrap.less, but replace panel.less with your file, and then compile that.

Comment: Yes both ways. 
By entering the @import "path" would give me an error. 
And I replaced my panel.less with my file it would look weird. :(

Comment: You have to replace  "path" with the path to bootstrap.less. And your panel.less should contain the same things as the original one, but with your changes.